# Myether wallet.com balance zero but I had a balance and it shows on the blockchain too

Tags: blockchain, ether, balances, myetherwallet, recovery

Please help as I have sent an email to my provider myetherwallet.com but so far no response sadly. My knowledge is very basic.

I opened an account added funds which showed several months ago but  today my balance says zero. Concerned I checked my address on the block chain for ethereum and it matches my balance that I originally held with this provider. Is this to do with the hrd fork? How do I get access to my funds. Sorry if this seems a dumb question but of course its concerning to have lost access and control of my funds.

Really appreciate your help guys.

Comment: I Have a very strange issue. I see 0.044 ETH in myetherwallet from 1 laptop and today i transferred another 0.5 ETH to my myetherwallet. Strange thing is they don't add up ? In Laptop 1 i just see 0.044 ETH whereas in laptop 2 i see 0.5 ETH ? please help. i am a beginner. Thanks,
Amrit

Answer (score 1):

Let me help you clarify a couple of things. The provider you are talking about MyEtherWallet.com is just a web based tool for Ethereum (ETH) handling. It creates wallets, transfer ETH from wallet to another, exchange ETH for other crypto-currencies etc. It is a site of tools. It does not hold accounts.

If you created a wallet there, that is great. But how did you fund the address? When you say you added funds, what site did you do this from? How did you add the ETH? Cash, credit, paypal, exchange it from one coin to the next?

In other words we need more info to help you. Do not post any codes or wallet info. I have a theory that you have the funds but you just do not know your holding them. If you have an address and you can look it up, then you have the funds. Well, that is if you know how to recover it.